# svn cleanup failed because pristine file could not be moved

Tags: svn

I wanted to use `svn cleanup` to remove lock on my working copy but failed with the following log:

```
svn: E000001: Can't remove file '/Users/panjie/Desktop/work/SYS-SVN/.svn/pristine/e4/e41bbcb7a645255ae62c65613e6d0dcbe7499d70.svn-base': Operation not permitted
```

I checked the permission of the file and found nothing wrong. I am using SVN/1.9.3 under MACOSX/10.11.6

Comment: just delete everything and do svn up.

Comment: It's a huge svn repository about 20GB and I am updating using VPN, so I don't want to just checkout everything out again. Also this problem occurred in two of my MACs so I want a solution for it.

Comment: Try 'svn up' after force removing that file i.e rm -f your file name.

Comment: Looks like a problem with permissions. Check whether you have full access to `/Users/panjie/Desktop/work/SYS-SVN/` including `.svn` and all the contents within.

Comment: 1. I have full access to file the files under SYS-SVN

Comment: 2. I delete that file and try `svn up` and failed again (almost the same error message except that it tells me could not find that file).

Answer (score 15):

The cause of this is that the file is locked by macOS. So, the solution is simple `chflags -R nouchg .svn` and run `svn cleanup` again and everything is OK now.

Comment: Huuuge thumbs up for this!

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using Linux and has the same problem, just run:

`chown <user>:<group> -R .svn`

Essentially the issue is incorrect permissions in svn, most likely somebody commited with root permissions.
If you do not your group, most likely using the same name as your linux user will work.
If this does not work either, check the file permissions with chmod and not the ownership of the files.